# Particular Software ServiceInsight not showing activity

Tags: nservicebus

Testing NServiceBus, I put through a message that failed, and it showed up in ServiceInsight as expected.  I fixed the root cause of the failure, and used ServiceInsight to retry the message.  This worked, and in ServiceInsight the message status changed from error to success.

I have subsequently processed a couple more messages successfully.  But these are not showing up in ServiceInsight at all.  The only message I'm still seeing in ServiceInsight is that initial failed on now still in a success state.  Is this by design?  Does ServiceInsight only show those messages that require(d) interaction by the administrator?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue. In my case it was happening because ServiceControl was not correctly configured.

You should enable AUDIT FORWARDING and configure a queue and also enable it on your endpoint.

[ServiceControl configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtFG7.png)

How to configure audit on your endpoint: http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/auditing

PS: Don't forget to use the same queue name.